# Importing mail boxes from cPanel host to DIY Postfix + Dovecot

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot, mailbox

I am migrating sites from a shared host which uses cPanel, moving files and databases are done. The only thing that I am stuck at is moving the mail boxes, cPanel uses Exim while I have installed Postfix + Dovecot on Ubuntu Server 12.04LTS

Is there a way to move them without losing any data?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving mailboxes can be as easy as copying other files/folders. You need to confirm the following:

1. Make sure that both email servers understand the same message format and file naming (maildir vs mbox). Also, use the same hierarchy in managing email directories.
2. Check the files/folders ownership and permissions and fix them if needed.

You can start by copying the files/folders of one user and make sure you can access them using POP/IMAP. If done successfully, you can do the rest.